# Right permute words from text

Tags: c, string, pointers

i have a text and i want to right permute every word from it while ignoring characters such as :" ",",","?","!",".",double quotes , single quotes.
I've tried a lot of approches but no one seems to work (i receive Segmentation Fault almost all the time).
Ex: for nr_permutari=1 and text=".abcd.!" , the text will become:".dabc!"

This is my code :

```
void permutari (char *text,char * nr_permutari) {

    int numar_permutari=atoi(nr_permutari);     
    int i,j,k; 
    for(j=1;j<=numar_permutari;j++)     {
        for (i=0; i <strlen(text)-1; i++)   { 
                k=i;
                while(*(text+k)!='\n' && *(text+k)!='.' 
                   && *(text+k)!=',' && *(text+k)!=' '
                   && *(text+k)!='?' && *(text+k)!='!')

                    k++;
                while(i<k-1) {
                    char *temp;
                    temp = *(text+i);
                    *(text+i) = *(text+i+1);
                    *(text+i+1) = temp;
                    i++;
                }
                i=k;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Quick way: First get rid of all unwanted characters by forming a new string. Then carry out permute operation.

Comment: @ARK if i'd do this way, i wouldn't be able to reproduce the unwanted characters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
while(*(text+k)!='\n' && *(text+k)!='.' 
               && *(text+k)!=',' && *(text+k)!=' '
               && *(text+k)!='?' && *(text+k)!='!')
```

needs to test for the `\0` (end of string)...

```
while(*(text+k)!='\n' && *(text+k)!='.' 
               && *(text+k)!=',' && *(text+k)!=' '
               && *(text+k)!='?' && *(text+k)!='!'
               && *(text+k))
```

Then

```
char *temp;
```

should be

```
char temp;
```

By the way `*(text+k)` is `text[k]` which is easier to read.

Comment: Works here. Did you do the 2 changes? What word did you try? What happens?

Comment: Yes I did.Just gave a random example , "aaaaa" .

Comment: Works. 1) check the code that should be exactly like above 2) how do you call *permutari*?

Comment: Text has around 2-3 lines of text and permutari as  1.I don't know then why it doens't work...

Comment: What is the text you try? If you call the function with a constant string, eg `permutari("aaaaa", "1")` this won't work since "aaaaa" cannot be changed. Do `char s[] = "aaaaa";permutari(s,...`

Comment: Oh . it's working now. The only problem is that they are not switching in the right order...

Comment: It's done . I understand now. It looks like i had some memory allocation problem.